# System of first order linear partial differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Is it possible that the following system of first-order linear partial differential equations has a solution?

$$\frac{\partial b_1(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_1}- b_1(x_1,x_2) f_1(x_1,x_2)=0,$$
$$\frac{\partial b_1(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_2}- b_1(x_1,x_2) f_2(x_1,x_2)=0,$$
where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are given and $b_1$ is unknown. All functions are real valued and smooth functions, say, on an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Check if the resulting equations for the mixed second derivative are compatible.

Comment: What about the case where there is no compatibility condition @LutzLehmann.

Comment: Then obviously there is no solution. Integrating the gradient field of $b_1$ around a circle should result in a zero difference, but if there is no compatibility, then that means that the vector field is no gradient field and the closed-loop integrals will almost all give non-zero values.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you  for your reply. In  the background, the field $b_i$ is gradient. Let me write the general system as follows
$$\frac{\partial b_1(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_1}- b_1(x_1,x_2) f^1_{11}(x_1,x_2)- b_2(x_1,x_2) f^2_{11}(x_1,x_2)=0,$$
$$\frac{\partial b_1(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_2}- b_1(x_1,x_2) f^1_{12}(x_1,x_2)- b_2(x_1,x_2) f^2_{12}(x_1,x_2)=0,$$
$$\frac{\partial b_2(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_1}- b_1(x_1,x_2) f^1_{12}(x_1,x_2)- b_2(x_1,x_2) f^2_{12}(x_1,x_2)=0,$$
$$\frac{\partial b_2(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_2}- b_1(x_1,x_2) f^1_{22}(x_1,x_2)- b_2(x_1,x_2) f^2_{22}(x_1,x_2)=0.$$

Comment: So the accurate question is; what about the case when the compatibility condition is satisfied? @LutzLehmann

Comment: You can always get a candidate for the solution function by integrating along rays from the initial point. The compatibility conditions make the path integrals path-independent, so that the integrals are just functions of the end points, not of the path between them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarification @LutzLehmann.